# element.setCustomValidity does not seem to work

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, dom

I have a change event on an email field that is supposed to validate that the email address is unique using an ajax call.  The problem is that it is telling me that the element does not support the setCustomValidity method.  Please Help.

```
$("#tbEmail").change(function (event) {
    var obj = new Object();

    obj.email = $("#tbEmail").val();
    var params = JSON.stringify(obj);

    $.ajax
    (
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "./controllers/Consumer.aspx/validateEmail",
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.d != 0) {

                    var element = $("#tbEmail");
                    element.setCustomValidity('The email address entered is already registerd.');
                    alert(element.checkValidity());
                    alert(element.validationMessage);
                }
                else {
                    $("#tbEmail").setCustomValidity("");
                };
            },
            error: function (result) { ProcessError(result) }
        }
    );

})
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`setCustomValidity` is DOM API not jQuery API. In your code you are trying to call it on jQuery instance. So you need to first get the DOM element instance & then call the API.

Also it needs to be HTML5 compliant browser and a form.

```
 var element = $("#tbEmail")[0];
 element.setCustomValidity('The email address entered is already registerd.');
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much vinayakj.  I would have played with that for days and not thought of that.  How do I accept an answer?  I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: or you can do document.getElementById('tbEmail').setCustomValidity('The email address entered is already registerd.');

Answer (score 7):

A simpler approach to this, adding "[0]":

```
$("#tbEmail")[0].setCustomValidity("")
```

Answer (score 5):

use `get(0)`.

```
    var element = $("#tbEmail").get(0);
    element.setCustomValidity('The email address entered is already registerd.');
```

Answer (score -6):

$("#tbEmail").setCustomValidity("Error msg")

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Downvote: First: there is no explanation, Second: this is just wrong. It has the same failure as the questioner. I hope nobody will read this.